# Spring i18n Automation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, internationalization

Is there's any way to automate string extraction from jsp files then put them as keys in spring message properties files for each supported language.

So for example in jsp i just write something like

```
<span>_(Hello World)</span>
```

Then run the tool which will extract "Hello World" & put it in all message properties files for each supported language & checking if it already exist to avoid duplicates, ..

Finally it replace it to be like

```
<span><spring:message code="hello_world" text="default text" /></span>
```

---

**EDIT:**

Or even better a jsp function like:

```
<span><%= _("Hello World") %></span>
```

In this case the function will convert the string to user chosen locale specific string and nothing is replaced in jsp file.

Comment: I do not think so, start writing your own tool.

Comment: That's weird I though this problem is solved in spring like for example with PHP + gettext. I started writing my own tool & will post here github link when it's finished.

Comment: If you're looking for something gettext based, maybe you can use or reuse some code from my project here: https://github.com/jhorstmann/i18n